# What remainder do you get when dividing a big number with 9999 digits by 37?

Tags: number-theory

Recently a friend asked me a question that he was given at the interview.
It is stated as follows:

"What remainder do you get when dividing $9989...91$ by $37$?"

$9989...91$ the first digits are $9989$ and the last are $91$ what is in the middle is unknown. The number has $9999$ digits in total.

The question is stated exactly like this. No other information was given.

Comment: So... what's the fifth digit supposed to be?

Comment: HINT: $999=37 \cdot 27$.

Comment: The digits between 9989 and 91 are unknown.

Comment: @IgorZimenko Then the remainder is also unknown. I could at mst tell you the remainder when dividing by 100

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Well, if the number is divided by 100 then the answer is obvious. But, the question  asked what is the remainder if this number is divided by 37. I am curious is there a solution for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can represent your number as
$$
N=9989\cdot10^{9995}+100x+91
$$
with a suitable limitation for $x$.

We have $9989\equiv-1\pmod{37}$, $\varphi(37)=36$, $9995\equiv23\pmod{36}$ and $10^{9995}\equiv10^{23}\equiv26\pmod{37}$. Also $100\equiv26\pmod{37}$ and finally $91\equiv 17\pmod{37}$.

Therefore $9989\cdot10^{9995}\equiv -26\pmod 37$. So your number
$$
N\equiv-26+26x+17\equiv26(x-1)+17\pmod{37}
$$
There is no way to conclude, unless you know the remainder of $x$ modulo $37$: the remainder can be any integer between $0$ and $36$ inclusive.